# Deploy Operating system specific custom node in node-red library

Tags: node-red

I have created a custom node library have few nodes for an ST Linux board. In this library, I created a c addon. Since my addon is build using a platform SDK for ST Linux, this node can only run on this OS/board. While deploying it on the node-red library, is it possible to add some restriction that it can only to be installed on the selected OS. The reason to this restriction is that this node can not work on any other OS.

I want to know if it is possible and if so, how?

For any more inputs/clarifications, please do ask.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to add any restrictions at the Node-RED level, or in the node catalogue.

The best you can do is to make it plain that node will not work on other platforms in the README.md of the package. This will be shown on the flows.nodered.org site that hosts the catalogue of nodes.

You may be able to use the `package.json` to also help warn what OS and CPU architecture `npm` will allow the node to install on by setting the `os` and `cpu` flags. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#os

The node should fail to install if the native compile fails, but you could also add some defensive code to catch errors if the native component fails to load so it can print meaningful errors rather than crash.

Comment: So, if I will specify the OS as os='xyz', will it not only work on the specific os?

Comment: npm will print large warnings if the OS doesn't match, but there is no way to stop a user trying to install packages.

Comment: Oh. So, even if I will set the os configuration, this will still install on any unsupported os. That's not good. Customer doesn't want these nodes to be installed on unsupported OS :(

Comment: Added check for the os and now, it can not be installed on windows etc os and prompts error saying unsupported os and installation fails. For the correct os, it installs